# ASP.NET Identity Update User - Nullreference

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, asp.net-identity

Im trying to update an User and get nullreference. 
This is my code for updating user, i get the nullreference when i set the firstname in the else (when the object dont exist, then i tried to create it but it dont work)

the properties work fine, because my registration works and if the userprofile object exist on the user it's also fine

```
  var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        if (currentUser.UserProfileInfo != null)
        {

            currentUser.UserProfileInfo.FirstName = Firstname.Text;
            currentUser.UserProfileInfo.LastName = Lastname.Text;
            currentUser.UserProfileInfo.Adress = Adress.Text;
            currentUser.UserProfileInfo.Zip = Zip.Text;
            currentUser.UserProfileInfo.City = City.Text;
            currentUser.UserProfileInfo.Mobile = Mobile.Text;

            manager.UpdateAsync(currentUser);

        }
        else
        {

            UserProfileInfo UserProfileInfo = new UserProfileInfo();
            currentUser.UserProfileInfo.FirstName = Firstname.Text;
            currentUser.UserProfileInfo.LastName = Lastname.Text;
            currentUser.UserProfileInfo.Adress = Adress.Text;
            currentUser.UserProfileInfo.Zip = Zip.Text;
            currentUser.UserProfileInfo.City = City.Text;
            currentUser.UserProfileInfo.Mobile = Mobile.Text;

            manager.UpdateAsync(currentUser);

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: [what is a nullreferenceexception and how do i fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s5p4.html < use breakpoints to help you with the debugging process (i.e. find out what is throwing the exception)

Comment: I get the error if the userinfo doesent exist on one user, i have to figure out how to check if it exixt and if not create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible scenarios come to my mind. It is difficult to say with this little information but here is my input:

- You are not logged in while trying to use User.Identity.GetUserId(). This will return a null value for id and thus resulting in null currentUser. You are not checking if currentUser is null so that results in null reference exception when you are trying to access properties of null object.
- You get the ApplicationUser object but the UserProfileInfo property is not created. There can be many reasons behind this depending on your implementation.

You should set your breakpoint on the follow row

```
currentUser.UserProfileInfo.FirstName = Firstname.Text;
```

And check if currentUser is null or UserProfileInfo is null.

Try this:

```
else
{

    currentUser.UserProfileInfo = new UserProfileInfo();
    currentUser.UserProfileInfo.FirstName = Firstname.Text;
    currentUser.UserProfileInfo.LastName = Lastname.Text;
    currentUser.UserProfileInfo.Adress = Adress.Text;
    currentUser.UserProfileInfo.Zip = Zip.Text;
    currentUser.UserProfileInfo.City = City.Text;
    currentUser.UserProfileInfo.Mobile = Mobile.Text;

    manager.UpdateAsync(currentUser);

}
```

Comment: It's that the userprofileinfo doesent exist on the user i updated my code.

Comment: You should set currentUser.UserProfileInfo = new UserProfileInfo(); Instead on the first row inside else statement